# Bootstrap multi select drop down list required class not working properly

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I used the following form to insert multiple items at a time to a MySQL table.

[Item Insert View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vCdkX.png)

### Required Result & Tried

I want to insert checkbox selected items only at a time and others can be inserted later. So, I want to make the fields office and branch as required for selected rows only.

I made the fields as follows to do that.

```
<td>
                                                <select name="office[]" id="office[]" required class="form-control select2 ">
                                                    <option value=""></option>
                                                    <?php
                                                    if (!empty($offices)) {
                                                        foreach ($offices as $row) {
                                                            ?>
                                                            <option value="<?= $row->office_id ?>"><?= $row->office_name ?></option>
                                                            <?php
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                    ?>
                                                </select>
                                            </td>

                                            <td>
                                                <select  name="branch[]" id="branch[]" required class="form-control select2">
                                                    <option value=""></option>
                                                    <?php
                                                    if (!empty($branches)) {
                                                        foreach ($branches as $row) {
                                                            ?>
                                                            <option value="<?= $row->branch_id ?>"><?= $row->branch_name ?></option>
                                                            <?php
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                    ?>
                                                </select>
                                            </td>
```

### Outs

The function is working properly. But the required class applied for all the rows including unselected (Check Boxes) rows.

What can be changed in my code to do this ? Can anyone help ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. What function? Note that `required` is an _attribute_, not a class.